# With several sites on the same server and different rules for HTTP/HTTPS a non-secure site is getting redirected to a different secure one

Tags: https, apache2

I have an Apache server that will be serving up a few sites (all from the same IP address).

Site A must be accessible via HTTP and HTTPS.

Site B must *only* be accessible via HTTP - it cannot be accessed via https.

Site A works fine, but Site B is giving me trouble. When a user attempts to access `https://SiteB` they get redirected to `https://SiteA`.

The config for Site A looks like this:

```
# 001-SiteA.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName SiteA
  ServerAlias SiteA
  # ...
</VirtualHost>

# 001-SiteA-SSL.conf:
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName SiteA
  ServerAlias SiteA
  # ...
</VirtualHost>

# 002-SiteB.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName SiteB
  ServerAlias SiteB
  # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

What is preferred is that the user get a 404 error or an empty page or something - but definitely *not* the content of SiteA.

Why is `https://SiteB` redirecting users to `https://SiteA` and how can I stop that?

Comment: What are your other virtual hosts, especially your `:443` ones?   You may have to create a dummy virtual host for `SiteB:443`.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: I've added more details to the question.

Comment: Apache treats the first virtual host for each port as the default.   The fact that siteB doesn't have a `:443` virtual host configured means that requests for it will use siteA's.

Comment: Even though the server name doesn't match? Seriously? If this is defined behaviour, I might need a link to reference, to prove to someone here that I'm not crazy.

Comment: I guess the correct solution is to just add a VirtualHost *:443 for SiteB and explicitly redirect to an error page, or something like that, yes?

Comment: That is why I always create `0000-default.conf` and `0000-default-ssl.conf` that just serve up error messages.  Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427379/apache-default-virtualhost

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Good point. Could you put that in as an answer so that I can accept it as *the* answer? Also, if you do have a link to the apache documents that explain this, I really could use it. Or if you can just name this behaviour, I'll look it up myself.

Comment: Keep in mind that Apache server software predates virtual hosts.   This is holdover from the days when there could only be one web site per server and it was expected to respond to any and all host names.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apache documentation for name based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) states (emphasis is theirs):

> #### The default name-based vhost for an IP and port combination
>
> If no matching ServerName or ServerAlias is found in the set of virtual hosts containing the most specific matching IP address and port combination, then **the first listed virtual host** that matches that will be used.

Because you don't have a virtual host defined for `siteB:443` it is defaulting to `siteA:443` because it is the first one matching the IP address and port number.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Create a virtual host for `siteB:443`
2. Create virtual hosts to handle unknown host names.  Have them return error codes.   Have them come first in the list by naming the config files like `0000-default-site.conf` and `0000-default-site-ssl.conf`

I'd recommend the default site solution, otherwise SiteA will be served up for any random host name that is pointed to the server.

Comment: Actually, I'm finding that using a default config in `000-default.conf` is also capturing traffic to SiteA and sending *that* to the default page. :(

Comment: Check that you don't have a real ServerName or ServerAlias in the default and siteA.conf has the correct ServerName.  Also make sure 000-default comes first,   If you already have conf with three zeros, use four.

Comment: I checked those things, but since other people are using this server now (it's a test server, but other people test other things on it), I've gone back to Option 1: creating a virtual host for SiteB:443. I'd like to figure out why the default sites didn't work, but no time for it today probably.

Comment: The default config for `virtualhost *:443` does NOT have a ServerName/ServerAlias. I renamed it to 999-default-ssl.conf and now SiteA works properly for http and https but SiteB:443 goes to SiteA:443, if I don't have an explicit virtualhost defined for SiteB:443.

Comment: at 999 it will come last and not work.   Try it first with `ServerName localhost`.

Comment: @Hmm hadn't thought of trying with localhost. Will report back later...

Comment: So far, it looks like using `ServerName localhost` in a `000-default-ssl.conf` for `<VirtualHost: *:443>` seems to work.